# Can't delete with sed

Tags: sed, delete

I have this text in `/etc/bash.bashrc`:

```
alias dwa='bash /opt/dwa.sh'
```

I tried to delete it with the following *(and similar commands)*:

```
sed -i 'alias dwa=\'bash /opt/dwa.sh\'/d' /etc/bash.bashrc
```

Why did my `sed` operation fail?

Comment: You can't escape anything in single quotes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why search and replace when you can delete?

```
sed --in-place '/^alias dwa=/d' /path/to/file
```

Answer (score -2):

```
awk '!/alias dwa/{print $0}' filename
```

Comment: That's not editing in place, and the `{print $0}` is wholly unnecessary